# How to get a convolution of 3 or more continuous PDFs to obtain the average of the PDFs in Python and or R

Tags: python, r, statistics, probability, convolution

Say I have three random variables. I would like to do a convolution to obtain the **average**. How do I do this in Python and or R?

#### Edit 1

Also. It seems the default behavior is to have the convolution size larger than any of the inputs. I will assume that all of the inputs are the same size. Is it possible to have the resulting convolution the same size as the vectors which are being used as inputs to the convolution?

For example, if `x1` is `n=100` then I would like the resulting convolution to be `n=100`

### Edit 2 - Added Example

I theory the convolution should be close to what I can calculate analytically.

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
n, u1, u2, u3, sd = 100, 10, 20, 6, 5
u_avg = np.mean([u1,u2,u3])
a = rng.normal(u1, sd, size=n)
b = rng.normal(u2, sd, size=n)
c = rng.normal(u3, sd, size=n)
z = rng.normal(u_avg, sd/np.sqrt(3), size=n)
convolution = rng.choice(reduce(np.convolve, [a, b, c]), size=n)

print("true distribution")
print(np.round(np.quantile(z, [0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99]), 2))
print("convolution")
print(np.round(np.quantile(convolution, [0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99]),2))
```

If the convolution is working then the `convolution` should be close to the `true` distribution.

```
true distribution
[ 3.9   9.84 12.83 14.89 18.45]
convolution
[5.73630000e+03 5.47855750e+05 2.15576037e+06 6.67763665e+06
 8.43843281e+06]
```

It looks like the convolution is not even close.

Comment: The convolution needs to be applied to a discretization of the pdf's, not a random sample. Try `conv` from the package `pracma` as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I think you misused the "convolution" to calculate the PDF of summation of independent normally distributed random variables. It should be noted that, the convolution is applied to the PDFs, rather than the random variables.

Below is an example code that may help you to find the result you want. Given the initial random variables `u1`, `u2`, `u3` like below

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
u1 <- 10
u2 <- 20
u3 <- 6
SD <- 5
u <- mean(c(u1, u2, u3))

x1 <- rnorm(n, u1, SD)
x2 <- rnorm(n, u2, SD)
x3 <- rnorm(n, u3, SD)
z <- rnorm(n, u, SD / sqrt(3)) # the random variable that is generated from the objective (desired) distribution
```

and you should use the following operation to construct the objective random variable `x`, if you want to work on the **random variables** `x1`, `x2` and `x3`:

```
x <- rowMeans(cbind(x1, x2, x3))
```

and you will see that

```
> mean(x)
[1] 12.16792

> sd(x)
[1] 2.752923
```

while the "desired" statistics are

```
> u
[1] 12

> SD / sqrt(3)
[1] 2.886751
```

---

## Previous Answer Regarding "Convolution"

You can try `conv` from package `pracma`

```
> library(pracma)

> x <- c(1, 2)

> y <- c(2, 3, 4)

> z <- c(-1, 0, 1, 5)

> Reduce(conv, list(x, y, z))
[1] -2 -7 -8  9 45 58 40
```

Comment: This isn't incorrect, but it's incomplete; convolution needs to be applied to the pdf or pmf of the distributions (probably a discretization of the continuous distributions in question since computing the integrals either symbolically or numerically is probably beyond the scope of the question). NB: `conv` from `pracma` does what's needed here, but built-in `convolve` applies circular convolution by default, which is something different, and I don't know if it's possible to get the right result by setting the `type` argument for `convolve`.

Comment: @RobertDodier It seems you know a lot about this. Maybe you can provide a complete solution. One issue I am having with the above solution is that is seems to be a **sum** as opposed to an **average**. I ran `library(pracma)x <- rnorm(100,10,5);y <- rnorm(100,20,5);z <- rnorm(100,6,5);Reduce(conv, list(x, y, z))`. The result is `685.2557    3497.9491    7223.6213   10086.6520   14765.5374 .....` These values seem too large to be an average.

Comment: @Alex I don't think you really understood the motivation of using convolution here: The convolution should be applied to PDFs, not the random variables (but your are using `rnorm` in your example, which is pointless for the convolution if you want to see the distribution of the average of `(a,b,c)`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am misunderstanding. Can I convince the ecdf if the samples are large enough? Or are you saying I should not consider the convolution operation at all. In that case how would you say I should proceed

Comment: @Alex You should not consider convolution for ***random variables***, since it is pointless and has no meaning from the statistical perspective

Comment: Thanks again. Forgive my lack of understanding on this topic. What am I really looking for here if it is not convolution?

Comment: @Alex I guess you wanted to verify the convolution of PDFs and in turn check the resulting random variables, but you seem not working on the right track. Maybe you should read about this carefully first https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions

Comment: @ThomasisCoding thanks. “It should be noted that, the convolution is applied to the PDFs, rather than the random variables.” This was ignorance on my part. Now I have a second question. In the example I gave I knew the RVs were normal. Say I do not know their source distribution. Would it be valid to calculate the desired distribution via bootstrap?

Comment: @Alex I don't know about bootstrap so I am not able to help you out there